# Symbol for a FIFO / Queue in dia?

Tags: queue, diagram, fifo, dia

I am working on some diagram of architecture - and I need to include our queuing frameworks.

I am using dia - however I am not able to find any symbol which may fit - and I think it miss option to search inside the 'shapes'.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Dia's Sybase sheet has a "Stable storage device" which is a "queue" - but possibly not the symbol you're looking for.

http://diashapes.appspot.com/ allows you to search for shapes - in case you're getting a strange error message, the app may be over the Google App Engine quota and you can try again later.

If these two options are not what you're looking for - could you describe the wanted symbol?

Comment: Actually I don't really know.... What I need to present is a our own queue framework + RabbitMQ itself.... Any idea how I should approach it to make it correct?

Comment: As you're dealing with software/hardware architecture - why don't you use UML diagrams (e.g. a deployment diagram)? This would automatically solve your symbol problem (Because your "queue frameworks" would become UML components.

Comment: Which component is a queue component?